# Em trigger temos INSERTED e DELETED. Por que não "UPDATED"?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

#### Cenário exemplo:

Tenho a tabela/campos:

- `documentos`

  - `id`
  - `documento`
  - `pessoa`
  - `item`
  - `qtd`
  - `valor`

O sistema dá `INSERT` e depois `UPDATE` nessa tabela numa sequência contínua (o que não viria ao caso).

O que gostaria é:

Quando fizer o `UPDATE`, verificar alguns parâmetros e se a condição for verdadeira, a trigger fazer outro `UPDATE` depois.

O que fiz:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TG_TEST1] 
   ON  [CORP].[dbo].[DOCUMENTOS] 
   AFTER UPDATE

AS

    DECLARE @DOC_ID INT
    DECLARE @DOC_QTD FLOAT

    SELECT TOP 1 @DOC_ID = ID, @DOC_QTD = QTD
    FROM dbo.DOCUMENTOS
    WHERE PESSOA = 3
    AND ITEM = 1
    ORDER BY ID DESC

    IF (@DOC_ID IS NOT NULL)

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    UPDATE dbo.DOCUMENTOS
    SET QTD = (@DOC_QTD * 1000)
    WHERE ID = @DOC_ID

END
```

---

#### Problema:

O problema é que acredito que o `SELECT TOP 1` esteja causando algum problema interno na aplicação (o que não convém postar, pois é uma aplicação específica).

Vi que tem o `INSERTED` e `DELETED`, mas não existe o `UPDATED` que eu possa já pegar o registro que foi alterado.

---

#### Dúvida:

Gostaria de saber, **como eu pegaria o `ID` do registro que está sendo feito o `UPDATE`**, além de outros dados para filtrar alguns valores e fazer a condição se será realizado o outro `UPDATE` ou não?

Comment: Na alteração você tem a condição, então seria o caso fazer um _select_ antes do `update` e controlar o que precisa fazer já com o id correto? (entendo que este não é o ponto da pergunta, e caso não esteja tendo problema em contornar isso, pode ignorar o questionamento =p)

Comment: @rLinhares Não, tenho uma condição pelo update feito, e realizou outro update caso a condição for verdadeira. Acho que é o que você está tentando dizer! rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (...) *como eu pegaria o ID do registro que está sendo feito o UPDATE, além de outros dados para filtrar alguns valores e fazer a condição se será realizado o outro UPDATE ou não*

Como o procedimento de gatilho [TG_TEST1] está declarado como AFTER UPDATE, então é certo que ele somente será acionado nos casos em que houver instrução UPDATE para a tabela CORP.dbo.DOCUMENTOS. Nesse caso estão disponíveis as tabelas virtuais INSERTED e DELETED, numa relação 1:1 entre elas. Na primeira (INSERTED) estarão as imagens das linhas que tenham sido alteradas, após a execução de UPDATE; na segunda (DELETED) as imagens das linhas alteradas, mas antes da execução do UPDATE.

É preciso ficar atento que um procedimento de gatilho pode ser acionado para tratar nenhuma, uma ou mais linhas. O primeiro passo é verificar se não há nem uma única linha alterada. Eis uma forma:

```
...
-- verifica se houve alteração
IF not exists (SELECT * from INSERTED)
  return;
...
```

Para essa verificação acima tanto faz testar ou a tabela virtual INSERTED ou a DELETED, pois entre elas há uma relação 1:1 quando o procedimento de gatilho é somente do tipo AFTER UPDATE.

O restante do código deve ser construído considerando-se que pode existir mais de uma linha alterada. Deve-se então acessar as tabelas DELETED e/ou INSERTED para obter quais linhas foram alteradas na tabela associada.

Somente como exemplo, eis um modelo derivado do código postado no tópico:

```
...
UPDATE Doc
    set QTD = Ins.QTD * 1000
    from INSERTED as Ins
         inner join DELETED as Del on Ins.ID = Del.ID
         inner dbo.DOCUMENTOS as Doc on Doc.ID = Ins.ID
    where ... 
...
```

Na cláusula WHERE devem-se adicionar os filtros.

Juntando as partes, tem-se algo como:

```
-- código #1 v2
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TG_TEST1 
     on CORP.dbo.DOCUMENTOS 
     after UPDATE as

begin
-- verifica se houve alteração
IF not exists (SELECT * from INSERTED)
  return;

--
UPDATE Doc
    set QTD = Ins.QTD * 1000
    from INSERTED as Ins
         inner join DELETED as Del on Ins.ID = Del.ID
         inner dbo.DOCUMENTOS as Doc on Doc.ID = Ins.ID
    where ... ;

end;
go
```

---

Sugestão de leitura:
 - artigo [Armadilhas na programação de procedimentos de gatilho
   (*trigger*)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/)

Comment: José, você está dizendo que, como eu já tenho o `after UPDATE`, então posso já utilizar o `INSERTED` ou `DELETED` sem verificar se os 2 tem registro, seria isso?

Comment: Se na declaração do procedimento de gatilho estiver definido somente "AFTER UPDATE", então é certa a existência das tabelas virtuais DELETED e INSERTED, numa relação 1:1. Se não houver nada na DELETED, então também não há nada na INSERTED; e vice-versa.

Answer (score 6):

Se a *trigger* for de INSERT, a INSERTED terá registros e a DELETED ficará vazia

Se a *trigger* for de DELETE, a INSERTED ficará vazia e a DELETED terá registros

Se a *trigger* for de UPDATE, a INSERTED e a DELETED terão registros

Nos casos dos *Updates*, as informações antigas(pré alteração) ficarão dentro da tabela DELETED, já as novas informações(alteradas) estarão dentro da INSERTED.

Na sua *trigger* você pode fazer assim:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM INSERTED )
    BEGIN
        /* é um UPDATE */     
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        /* é um DELETE */     
    END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM INSERTED )
    BEGIN
        /* é um INSERT */     
    END
END
```

Uma outra forma que também uso é jogar primeiro para uma variável qual ação está ocorrendo, exemplo:

```
SET @ACTION = 'I'; -- DEFINE INSERT POR PADRÃO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
BEGIN
    SET @ACTION = 
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) THEN 'U' -- FOI UM UPDATE
            ELSE 'D' -- FOI UM DELETE
        END
END

IF @ACTION = 'I'
BEGIN           
--CÓDIGO INSERT
END

IF @ACTION = 'U'
BEGIN           
--CÓDIGO UPDATE
END

IF @ACTION = 'D'
BEGIN           
--CÓDIGO DELETE
END
```

**Edit**

Conforme visto pelo [José Diz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57789/jos%c3%a9-diz), o procedimento é do tipo AFTER UPDATE, logo isso indica que sempre será um UPDATE

Comment: Poderia ser `IF EXISTS( (SELECT ID FROM DELETED)  AND (SELECT ID FROM INSERTED) )` ?

Comment: Sim, claro, inclusive uso esse rsrs, tentei deixar mais separado para ficar mais claro.

Comment: @rbz, adicionei uma outra forma que uso tbm.

Comment: Estava reparando na resposta, mas de onde busco o `ID` do registro em questão? Do `INSERTED` ou `DELETED`? Ou tanto faz?

Comment: se você não alterar o ID, tanto faz, se você alterar o antigo estará na `DELETED` e o novo na `INSERTED`.

Comment: Isso dela estar nas 2 não quer dizer que o SQL faz isso correto? Ou realmente não existe o "update", ele sempre faz delete e insert?

Comment: Então, não sei se todos os bancos de dados, mas os que conheço(MSSQL e MySQL) fazem assim, a engine deles faz primeiro o delete e depois o insert nos casos do Update, ou seja, o update é um delete seguido de insert.

Comment: Cara, nunca tinha reparado nisso. Abri uma nova pergunta: [UPDATE é um DELETE seguido de um INSERT?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325513/update-%C3%A9-um-delete-seguido-de-um-insert)

Comment: Como o procedimento de gatilho é do tipo AFTER UPDATE, então não é necessário verificar se o evento que acionou o gatilho é instrução INSERT, DELETE ou UPDATE, pois será sempre UPDATE.

Comment: @JoséDiz, bem visto, não havia percebido. Editei a pergunta.

Comment: @Barbetta Agradeço total a mão, foi muito útil. Mas o "critério" diferencial da questão, foi esse detalhe do `AFTER UPDATE` que o José disse, então por isso marquei a resposta dele. Mas no final, quem mais ganhou, fomos nós 2, que aprendemos tal detalhe tão significante. +1 ✌️

Comment: @rbz, concordo plenamente ;), tanto que quando editei dei o devido crédito. A resposta dele é a que melhor responde, a minha complementa ;)

Comment: @Barbetta Cara que bom que entende, porque tem uns que falam "Ah só porque o cara tem reputação, mimimi" kkk Valeu ✌️

Answer (score 1):

Achei bem curiosa a pergunta e fui pesquisar. [**Esse link**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/156604/) foi o que mais fez sentido pra mim.

A ideia nele é que seja criada uma forma de controlar o(s) arquivo(s) alterado(s) (variável/tabela) e depois retornar seu(s) id(s) (por exemplo). Entendi então que pode-se usar algo tipo assim:

```
DECLARE @alteracoes table([id_dept] int, [nome_antigo] varchar(50), [nome_novo] varchar(50));

UPDATE departamento
SET nome = 'nome_teste_novo'
OUTPUT id as id_dept, nome as nome_antigo, 'nome_teste_novo' as nome_novo
INTO @alteracoes
WHERE nome = 'nome_teste'

UPDATE dep
SET dep.nome = alt.nome_novo
FROM departamento as dep
INNER JOIN @alteracoes as alt ON dep.id = alt.id_dept

--aqui, @alteracoes contém os itens alterados
--select id_dept from @alteracoes
```

Comment: Vixe, não consegui entender. Devo declarar uma table com todos os campos da table em questão? Mas como eu filtro o ID para fazer a condição?

Comment: estava tentando entender/aplicar no seu problema e não acho que tenha muita diferença da forma que você faz; na minha resposta é possível controlar não após o update, mas quais arquivos serão alterados (seria um _"salvar ids que serão alterados e retornar depois"_) - o que não impede que essa alteração seja _um a um_.

Comment: Então, o problema é que acho que não ter o ID alterado, é o que está causando problemas... aí realmente não serviria 

Comment: entendi, e concordo.