# UPDATE é um DELETE seguido de um INSERT?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Em uma outra questão ([Em trigger temos INSERTED, DELETED, mas e o “UPDATED”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325488/em-trigger-temos-inserted-deleted-mas-e-o-updated)) surgiu essa dúvida quanto a forma execução do banco de dados, devido a forma que a *trigger* acessa um registro alterado.

#### Dúvidas

Quanto a um `UPDATE` (não em uma *trigger*), gostaria de saber:

- Quando fazemos um `UPDATE` o banco *deleta e depois insere* novamente o registro?
- Isto ocorre em todos os bancos?

Comment: Sei que em SQL Server isso acontece dessa forma mesmo, tem registos no `DELETED` , que correspondem ao registo anterior, e no `INSERTED` que correspondem ao novo registo.

Comment: @JoãoMartins onde são guardados esses registos DELETED e INSERTED?

Comment: São "tabelas" que estão disponíveis apenas dentro do próprio _trigger_. Exemplo: `SELECT * FROM inserted` irá devolver os registos que foram inseridos na tabela a que o _trigger_ está associado.

Comment: @JoãoMartins Importante ter dito, alterei a resposta para não parecer que é sobre trigger!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode ser. Depende! Não é igual em todos os sistemas gerenciadores de banco de dados.

Em certo sentido é sim, mas não quer dizer que precisa ser fisicamente assim. É um detalhe de implementação.

Em bancos de dados que usam MVCC é assim (boa parte dos DBs são ou usam um mecanismo parecido), ele nunca escreve por cima do que existe, sempre cria um novo, assim facilita muito a concorrência e o isolamento.

E pode ser mais adequando para lidar com mudanças na chave, afinal os dados costumam ser organizados em [árvores com chaves e valores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220409/101) (o valor costuma ser uma tupla, termo oficialmente usado na área) e se a chave muda o local da árvore onde o a tupla deve estar muda de lugar, portanto deve deletar de onde está e inserir em local novo. Pode ser a árvore da chave primária, ou das secundárias.

Mas há esquemas que isso não é tão verdade. Eu conheço alguns bancos que não são assim. Porém eles têm outros problemas. A própria deleção é complicada e muitas vezes ela nem acontece *online*, então o registro a ser apagado é apenas marcado com inválido e no futuro faz-se uma limpa em lote em tudo o que está marcado, uma espécie de coleta de lixo.

Mas em índices secundários eu acho que sempre é assim. Não vejo como não ser em condições normais. Não que não seja possível, mas é esquisito e não me parece uma solução muito realista. Entenda que a tabela normal que todos chamam costuma ser a própria chave primária, ao contrário do que muita gente pensa, ela também costuma ser um índice.

Mas em geral é mais um `INSERT` seguido de um `DELETE`, até para ser mais fácil de lidar com atomicidade. Só quando a inserção é completa e feito tudo o que precisa é que ele pode considerar que o antigo deva ser deletado.

Em caso de uso do *trigger* é inserido algo novo e depois do fim da operação é deletado o antigo, por isso ambos são visíveis. Alias, esse é mais um motivo para serem operações separadas.

Veja mais sobre índices:

- [Quais as diferenças entre os algoritmos HASH e BTREE usados em um índice?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/258193/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre clustered index e nonclustered index?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/198708/101)
- [O que são os índices, B-tree, hash, GiST e GIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101065/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Respondida e dada lição de casa!

Answer (score -2):

Nao , UPDATE é uma alteração de um campo do banco , que em sua operação não é realizado um delete antes , isto é visível quando voce faz uma trigger e voce consegue pegar a informanção que esta sendo alterada e comparar com a antiga (NEW e OLD)  e voce tambem pode verifica que o banco tem um campo senquencial chamado ID que ele nao é alterado diferentemente de quando vc deleta e insere